# Change support and resistance line color in mplfinance

Tags: mplfinance

Currently, I'm using this code. How can I change the `hlines` to red if it's a resistance and blue if it's a support?

```py
mplfinance.plot(df,  
                type = 'candlestick', 
                style = 'binance',
                hlines=dict(hlines= support_resistance,linestyle='-', linewidths = (1,1)),
                volume = True)
```

I'm getting results like this:

[image: picture here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
hlines=dict(hlines= support_resistance,linestyle='-',linewidths = (1,1),colors=('b','r')
```

See for example cell "`In [6]`" in this tutorial: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb

You may need to include as many colors as you have `support_resistance` lines.  So for example, maybe something like: `colors=['b','r','b','r','r','r']`

---

Regarding handling support resistance colors dynamically (per your comment) it is not appropriate for mplfinance to provide algorithms for determining support or resistance, only to provide tools to make it easier for you to visualize them.
Also, each user may have their own specific way of determining support or resistance.

Presumably as you are building the `support_resistance` list, at the point in your code where you are adding a specific price to that list, you probably know whether that price represents support or resistance.  At the same point in your code you should add a color ('b' or 'r') to the colors list.  That way you dynamic build two lists: `support_resistance`, and `colors` which end up being the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion from [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639359/daniel-goldfarb), I  made a list of colors as follows and it worked. support_resistance variable here consists of both support and resistance levels.

```
colors = []
for lvl in support_resistance:
    if lvl > df['Close'][-1]:
        colors.append('r')
    else:
        colors.append('b')
```